# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Table.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

Trying to display a filtered table, but unsuccessful, see below.

Keep getting an undefined error when reading map, can't seem to figure out why colleges aren't being passed when calling on `filteredColleges.map(college)`

Could this possibly be because I'm calling on the `<Table/>` component inside my `App.js` and forgot a basic step?

App.js looks like so:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Partners</h1>
        <Table/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If anyone could help I'd be very, very grateful. Thanks in advance!

```
import React , {Component } from 'react'

export default class Table extends Component {

// Display API data - componentDidMount - pull specific elements - DONE
// Create table displaying API data
// Create Search bar
// Create drop down list for prefix
// Style Ofsted Rating column

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            colleges: [],
            searchByName: ""
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ searchByName: event.target.value });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://collegesapi/data.json`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    colleges: result.getColleges
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                });
            }
        )
    }

    renderRow(college) {
        return (
            <tr key={college.id}>
                <td>{college.name}</td>
                <td>{college.groupPrefix}</td>
                <td>
                    {college.logo && (
                        <img className="w-full" src={college.logo} alt={college.name} />
                    )} 
                </td>
                <td>{college.ofstedRating}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }

    render() {

        const filterColleges = (colleges, query) => {
            if(!query) {
                return colleges;
            }

            return colleges.filter((college) => {
                const collegeName = college.name.toLowerCase();
                return collegeName.includes(query);      
            });
        };

        const filteredColleges = filterColleges(
            this.props.colleges,
            this.state.searchByName
        );

        const { error, isLoaded, colleges } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
            return ( 
                <div>

                <table className="table-fixed border-collapse">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Search partners"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th className="w-1/12">Partner</th>
                                <th className="w-1/12">Prefix</th>
                                <th className="w-1/12">Logo</th>
                                <th className="w-1/12">Ofsted Rating</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>{filteredColleges.map((college) => this.renderRow(college))}</tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring this.props.colleges while sending to "filterColleges" function:

```
const filteredColleges = filterColleges(
  this.props.colleges,
  this.state.searchByName
);
```

Instead, since you are setting it in states when received from API response, you should refer accordingly:

```
const filteredColleges = filterColleges(
  this.state.colleges,
  this.state.searchByName
);
```

Also, it is always good to handle error or empty responses, for example, if your API does not return even empty array, then this code will still throw the same error. So you can add null coalescing checks (??) and assign empty array in these cases, as shown below:

```
this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        colleges: result?.getColleges ?? [],
      });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Absolute legend mate! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @FelipeCruz, please refer the additional recommendation I have added.

Comment: Thanks so much @SujitSingh, I'll most certainly look further into this. If I could be cheeky and ask one more question, how would you approach having two separate search bars at the top of the table where the user can use one search bar to search by name and another to search by prefix? I've done this before with one search bar responsible for taking user input and providing results for multiple fields, but never with 2 separate search bars. The help you've already given is much appreciated so thank you once again!

Comment: Nevermind @SujitSingh mate, just done it. Really appreciate your help, I was getting very frustrated, you saved me a lot of time and sanity!

Comment: You are welcome @FelipeCruz, glad it helped!