# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') - Firestore API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am using react-admin to fetch data from a Firestore API in the following format:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "fields": {
        "teacher": {
          "stringValue": ""
        },
        "slot": {
          "stringValue": ""
        },
        "student_name": {
          "stringValue": ""
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2022-03-27T09:49:24.044423Z",
      "updateTime": "2022-03-29T13:50:41.264007Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "",
      "fields": {
        "teacher": {
          "stringValue": ""
        },
        "slot": {
          "stringValue": ""
        },
        "student_name": {
          "stringValue": ""
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2022-03-27T09:49:24.044423Z",
      "updateTime": "2022-03-29T13:50:41.264007Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "",
      "fields": {
        "teacher": {
          "stringValue": ""
        },
        "slot": {
          "stringValue": ""
        },
        "student_name": {
          "stringValue": ""
        }
      },
      "createTime": "2022-03-27T09:49:24.044423Z",
      "updateTime": "2022-03-29T13:50:41.264007Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I try to extract certain fields from the data like this,

```
const List = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  
    // Note: the empty deps array [] means
    // this useEffect will run once
    // similar to componentDidMount()
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("MY API URL")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
          (result) => {
            setIsLoaded(true);
            setItems(result);
          },
          // Note: it's important to handle errors here
          // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
          // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
          (error) => {
            setIsLoaded(true);
            setError(error);
          }
        )
    }, [])
  
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {

      return ( 
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              {item.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul> 
      );
    }
```

I am getting the following error : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**

I found a similar answers including this one here :  [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Table.render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548733/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map-table-render)

But was still unable to figure it out. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: isLoaded is being toggled before you're setting Items, maybe the refresh of the Loaded state tries to re-render, callings the `.map` function on items, which still hasn't been set it.. Maybe set the items first, than set the loaded state

Comment: @jasonmzx no that did not help, sorry. I was guessing maybe it was something to do with me accessing the items data structure incorrectly?

Comment: Well, have you console.log(result); ?  maybe try viewing that console log in chrome dev tools and view the strucutre, it's usually .body || .value or something to access the raw json, make sure your API resp isn't null aswell

Comment: @jasonmzx Yes I tried that. I played around with items , items['documents'] , items['documents'][0], { items.documents } and few others as well. Could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Optional Chaining(?.) at your items.

```
{items?.map(item => (
   <li key={item.id}>
      {item.name}
   </li>
 ))}
```

This should prevent the error.

Another important thing is that `result` you get back from your `fetch` request might probably be `undefined` and would raise the TypeError.